# Передача содержимого консоли Python 3 в .txt файл

Tags: python-3.x

Ежедневно скрипт отправляет на ftp-сервер некий файл. У ftplib есть функция set_debuglevel(). Задал нужный мне аргумент "1" и в консоль красиво начали выводиться сообщения типа:

```
*cmd* 'USER ftpusr'
*resp* '331 Password required for ftpusr.'
*cmd* 'PASS ********'
*resp* '230 User logged in.'
*cmd* 'CWD r0'
*resp* '250 CWD command successful.'
*cmd* 'TYPE I'
*resp* '200 Type set to I.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,67,4,34).'
*cmd* 'STOR 150419'
*resp* '125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.'
*resp* '226 Transfer complete.'
*cmd* 'QUIT'
*resp* '221 Goodbye.'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как содержимое консоли передать в .txt файлик. 
И есть ли возможность замены штатных сообщений на свои? Например не "*resp* '226 Transfer complete.'", а "Файл успешно загружен!"

Мне необходимо каждый раз удостоверяться, что файл передан на ftp-сервер.

Comment: Открой код скрипта и замени вывод в консоль на вывод в файл. Или просто добавть, чтоб было и туда, и сюда. Там же заменяется и текст сообщений.

Comment: Дополню комментарий выше, можно не через `print` выводить, а через `logger`, тогда можно настроить чтобы выводилось и в консоль, и в файл. Пример могу показать, это несложно. Еще можно через команды консоли перевести вывод скрипта в файл

Comment: @Эникейщик вся проблема в том, что никаких print() в коде нет. Я указываю set_debuglevel(1) и в консоль выводятся сообщения.

Comment: Тогда видимо уже через logger сделано, как gil9red советует.

Comment: @gil9red, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать вывод через logger, если в коде вообще нет никаких print()? Просто указав set_debuglevel(1),  в консоль выводится вся нужная мне информация.

Comment: @n.one.k, посмотрел в исходники ftplib.py и могу сказать, что тот точно не работает через logger, там через `print` выводятся сообщения, например: `        if self.debugging > 1:
            print('*get*', self.sanitize(line))`. Как вариант, можно перехватывать вывод в stdout и выводить в файл

Comment: @gil9red спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел в исходники `ftplib.py` и могу сказать, что тот точно не работает через `logger`, там через `print` выводятся сообщения, например:

```
if self.debugging > 1:
    print('get', self.sanitize(line))`
```

Как вариант, можно перехватывать вывод в `stdout` и выводить в файл.

Пример через `redirect_stdout`:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from ftplib import FTP

with open('ftp_log.txt', 'w') as f, redirect_stdout(f):
    # Пример кода взял из https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html

    ftp = FTP('ftp.debian.org')     # connect to host, default port
    ftp.login()                     # user anonymous, passwd anonymous@

    ftp.cwd('debian')               # change into "debian" directory
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')           # list directory contents

    ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)

    ftp.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если скрипт запускается в bash, то можно перенаправить ввод в нужный вам файл с помощью встроенных методов.

Выглядит примерно так:

```
python your_script > file_name.txt
```

Судя по описанию, файл запускается с периодичностью, этот вариант может подойти для элементарного сохранения, без изменений в коде библиотеки.

Но рекомендовал бы вам дописать/отредактировать под себя библиотеку сделав свой форк.